# The table with name already exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to solve this issue

when doing

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I am getting

```
In SchemaException.php line 108:
The table with name 'chris_test_sonata.page__block' already exists.
```

Obviously, the table isn't existing in my database. To be sure it was not something cache related I even made the operation with a new database I just created, the result is the same.

When I search for page__block occurences in my project I only find this mapping

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="page__block")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class SonataPageBlock extends BaseBlock
```

So there should not be other mapping for this table.

I also have a block.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <!--
         This file has been generated by the EasyExtends bundle ( https://sonata-project.org/easy-extends )

         References :
            xsd                  : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/doctrine-mapping.xsd
            xml mapping          : http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/xml-mapping/en
            association mapping  : http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/association-mapping/en
    -->
    <entity
        name="App\Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Block"
        table="page__block"
        repository-class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository">

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>

    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

There is some other occurences but all in dev.log

And I also have this in a cache file from symfony dev/pools

```
<?php

namespace Symfony\Component\VarExporter\Internal;

return $getExpiry ? PHP_INT_MAX : Hydrator::hydrate(
    $o = [
        clone (($p = &Registry::$prototypes)['Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Entity'] ?? Registry::p('Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Entity')),
        clone ($p['Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Table'] ?? Registry::p('Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Table')),
        clone ($p['Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\HasLifecycleCallbacks'] ?? Registry::p('Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\HasLifecycleCallbacks')),
    ],
    null,
    [
        'stdClass' => [
            'name' => [
                1 => 'page__block',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        $o[0],
        $o[1],
        $o[2],
    ],
    []
);
```

I have no idea what is wrong with it and why the mapping is'nt working.

Comment: Looks like you are defining the entity table two times. Try using just the xml or the annotation for the definition, not both that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have `Block` entity with table `page__block` and you created a new entity `SonataPageBlock` with same table name. If you change table name of `SonataPageBlock` everything be fine, but it will be 2 different tables in database.

If you are looking way for extending base entity you can read about [Table Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance).

Comment: You right I didn't saw it wasn't the same classname. The files were auto generated,

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who finds this on a search, receiving this error means that the table name already exists within an annotation.

`@ORM\Table(name="page__block")`

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem with ManyToMany relationship. I was declaring the associative table twice ( one time in each entity )

Answer (score 1):

In my case with Sylius there was an entity class that extends an entity from a plugin.
I did fix it by adding a class model in **config/packages/_sylius.yaml** :

```
sylius_taxonomy:
    resources:
        taxon:
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\Taxonomy\Taxon
```